# Cambio de formato datos filas vs columnas Excel

Tags: excel

trataré de explicarme lo mejor posible...Incluso voy a subir unas imagenes para comentarles un problema que tengo (a lo mejor más sencillo de lo que parece) pero aún no se como solucionarlo...

Resulta que tengo unos datos de la siguiente manera:

[image: Datos actuales]

Y necesito que queden de la siguiente manera:

[image: Datos deseados]

Si pueden apreciar, deseo que al encontrar nuevamente una cédula en este caso 1053816846 se agregue el nuevo nivel con sus respectivos datos...Pense en utilizar la función transponer pero por obvias razones no fue de mucha utilidad.

Ojala me puedan ayudar.

Muchas gracias y saludos a tod@s,

Comment: A que te refieres con "encontrar la cédula", o sea, como es tu proceso de buscar/encontrar?. Por otro lado de donde salen los datos de los otros niveles? (otra hoja de excel, una base de datos, un archivo de texto, etc)

Comment: Ah ya vi que los datos de los otros niveles están en la misma hoja

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor sigue el [tour] y revisa [ask]. Falta que menciones que es lo que has investigado. Sobre  que intentaste utilizar la función `trasponer` es mejor que menciones las razones por las que no funcionó y que otra cosa has intentado o al menos que piensas que podría funcionar.

Comment: (va un tip un método es crear una columna para ser usada como llave que incluya la cédula y el nivel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Condiciones:**

1. Combinación de `Cédula` y `Nivel` es única
2. Los datos no contienen líneas en blanco
3. Los datos se encuentran en el rango `B2: F6`

**Requisitos:** Extraer combinaciones únicas de Cédula y Nivel mostrando todos los datos para cada Cédula en la misma linea

*Esta solución utiliza **`FormulaArrays`** que deben ser ingresadas presionando las teclas **`[Ctrl]` + `[Shift]` + `[Enter]`** simultáneamente. Podrá ver los símbolos **`{`** y **`}`** alrededor de la fórmula si se ha introducido correctamente*

**Rango de Extracción:** El rango de extracción se encuentra en `I2: Q6`. Los títulos del rango de extracción deben incluir cada `Nivel` y sus datos correspondientes.

**Campos y Formulas:**

**Cédula:** Introduzca esta **`FormulaArray`** en `I3` para extraer una lista de registros únicos de `Cédula`

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( $B$3:$B$6, MATCH( 0, COUNTIF( I$2:I2, $B$3:$B$6 ), 0 ) * 1 ), "" )
```

Luego copie la celda `I3` al rango `I4:I6`

**Nivel I:** Introduzca esta fórmula en `J3` y copie celda `J3` hasta celda `J6`

```
=IF(EXACT($I3,""),"",J$2)
```

**Estado, Nota y Fecha *(nivel I)*:** Introduzca esta **`FormulaArray`** en `K3`

```
=IF( EXACT( $I3, "" ), "", IFERROR(
INDEX( D$2:D$6, SMALL(
INDEX( ROW( $B$2:$B$6 ) + 1 - ROW($2:$2), 0 ) 
* INDEX( ( $B$2:$B$6 = $I3 ) * ( $C$2:$C$6 = $J3 ), 0 ),
( 1 + ROWS( $B$2:$B$6 ) - SUM( ( $B$2:$B$6 = $I3 ) * ( $C$2:$C$6 = $J3 ) ) ) ) ), "" ) )
```

Luego copie celda `K3` al rango `K4:K6` y luego al rango `L3:M6`

**Nivel II:** Introduzca esta fórmula en `N3` y copie celda `N3` hasta celda `N6`

```
=IF(EXACT($I3,""),"",N$2)
```

**Estado, Nota y Fecha *(nivel II)*:** Introduzca esta **`FormulaArray`** en `O3`

```
=IF( EXACT( $I3, "" ), "", IFERROR(
INDEX( D$2:D$6, SMALL(
INDEX( ROW( $B$2:$B$6 ) + 1 - ROW($2:$2), 0 ) * 
INDEX( ( $B$2:$B$6 = $I3 ) * ( $C$2:$C$6 = $N3 ), 0 ),
( 1 + ROWS( $B$2:$B$6 ) - SUM( ( $B$2:$B$6 = $I3 ) * ( $C$2:$C$6 = $N3 ) ) ) ) ), "" ) )
```

Luego copie celda `O3` al rango `O4:O6` y luego al rango `P3:Q6`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Sugiero leer las siguientes páginas para obtener una comprensión más profunda de los recursos utilizados:

[Excel functions (alphabetical)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188),

[Excel functions (by category)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5F91F4E9-7B42-46D2-9BD1-63F26A86C0EB),

[Create an array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-E43E12E0-AFC6-4A12-BC7F-48361075954D),

[Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7),

Acepte mis disculpas por mostrar las formulas en su versión en inglés, ya que esa es la versión que tengo en mi máquina.
Igualmente las paginas sugeridas están en inglés, sugiero usar un navegador con traducción.

Comment: Apenas hoy revise la respuesta, me sirvió bastante. Muchisimas gracias!